# getElementById or parseInt not working?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to write a simple form on HTML/Javascript where I type in a number, adds one and then displays it. I got it working but it was concatenating the one instead of adding it. I used the parseInt(), but it is showing "Nan". Any suggestions?

The HTML is:

```
<head> <link src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="grossSalary">
    <button type="button" onclick="calculateTax()"> 
    Generate Tax
    </button>
</body>
```

The Javascript is:

```
function calculateTax(){
   var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary");
   var salaryInteger = parseInt(salaryString);
   alert(salaryInteger + 1);
}
```

The "error" message I get is:

"Nan"

Comment: An additional note to the existing answers. You should always define the `radix` for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), `parseInt(salaryString, 10);`, otherwise you might get an unexpected result when someone decides to add a leading `0` to the salary.

Comment: Oh geez. This is my first stack overflow question and boy you guys are fast and geniuses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to extract value from input element:

```
var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary").value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `.value`

```
 var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary").value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value, which is missed in your code.

```
var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your javascript where you set the salaryString variable.
You need to make sure to collect the value of the element you are selecting. Like so:

```
var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary").value;
```

After you do that, your code should behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To find value from textbox you have to use .value. so update your JS code

```
function calculateTax(){
    var sal = document.getElementById("grossSalary");
    var salaryInteger = parseInt(sal.value);
    alert(salaryInteger + 1);
}
```

Comment: Just as a note: As the naming is `salaryString`  it would be better to have `var salaryString   = document.getElementById("grossSalary").value;` or change the naming to `var salaryElement = document.getElementById("grossSalary");` and then do `var salaryInteger = parseInt(salaryElement.value);`

Comment: if you use above method then you can use salaryString as reference of dom element and you can add other event listener directly i.e. salaryString.addEvenetListener(), so this is better than other option posted above.

Comment: My comment was about the naming, a `DOMElement` is not `String`, as of that storing it in a value called `salleryString` could be missleading (especially in larger code) The part after `or change the naming` only differs in the variable name to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value.
 So when you try like

```
var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary");
```

so here salaryString is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.

If you are looking fro get the value of the corresponding text box then use something like

```
var salaryString = document.getElementById("grossSalary").value;
```