# I can't parseInt the getElementsByClass function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a grade calculator website but I can't seem to turn the inputs from Strings into Integers. Here is my code:

```
 <form  name="myform" action="" method="GET">
    <div>
        <label for="cmps200">CMPS 200</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="cmps211">CMPS 211</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="cmps212">CMPS 212</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="btn" type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" onclick="myF()">
    <p> </p>

    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
function myF() {
    var courses3 = document.getElementsByClassName("threeCredits");
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < courses3.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(courses3[i]);
    }

    if(sum===0 || sum<=0){
        alert("Please enter valid inputs!");
    } else {
        alert(sum/9);
    }
}
```

Every time I press the submit button I get NaN. Please Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getElementById or parseInt not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104061/getelementbyid-or-parseint-not-working)

Comment: Please as a general practice remember to pass the radix to `parseInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 2):

Your `courses3[i]` is an element, not it's value. Use `courses3[i].value`.

And also in your `if` condition the `<=` actually also checks the first one, which is `===`. So you can remove it

```js
function myF() {
    var courses3 = document.getElementsByClassName("threeCredits");
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < courses3.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(courses3[i].value);
    }

    if( sum <= 0 ){
        alert("Please enter valid inputs!");
    } else {
        alert(sum/9);
    }
}
```

```html
<form  name="myform" action="" method="GET">
    <div>
        <label for="cmps200">CMPS 200</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="cmps211">CMPS 211</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="cmps212">CMPS 212</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="btn" type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" onclick="myF()">
    <p> </p>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to read value from control `parseInt(courses3[i].value)`

```js
function myF() {
    var courses3 = document.getElementsByClassName("threeCredits");
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < courses3.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(courses3[i].value);
    }

    if(sum===0 || sum<=0){
        alert("Please enter valid inputs!");
    } else {
        alert(sum/9);
    }
}
```

```html
 <form  name="myform" action="" method="GET">
    <div>
        <label for="cmps200">CMPS 200</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="cmps211">CMPS 211</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="cmps212">CMPS 212</label>
        <input type="number" name="three" class="threeCredits">
        <br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="btn" type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" onclick="myF()">
    <p> </p>

    </div>
</form>
```